# How do I iterate through a list in a TI-83 calculator program

Tags: list, ti-basic

I created a set of programs to calculate the area under a graph using various methods of approximation (midpoint, trapezoidal, simpson) for my Calculus class.

Here is an example of one of my programs (midpoint):

```
Prompt A,B,N
(A-B)/N->D
Input "Y1=", Y1
0->X
0->E
For(X,A+D/2,b-D/2,D)
Y1(x)+E->E
End
Disp E*D
```

Instead of applying these approximation rules to a function (Y1), I would like to apply them to a list of data (L1). How do I iterate through a list? I would need to be able to get the last index in the list in order for a "For Loop" to be any good. I can't do anything like L1.length like I would do in Java.

Comment: TI-83 or TI-84? Title says one, tag says the other.

Comment: @Chris: They are both essentially the same.  TI-84 is just a TI-83 with more memory and other things.

Comment: @Chris It is TI-83. I was unable to create a new tag for the 83. Programming for the 84 should be exactly the same as for the 83.

Comment: @Jeff: still, it offends my righteous soul to see clashing labelling :-) Didn't notice the fact that the ti-84 was only used once before and ti-83 doesn't exist... someone should create the tag and retag a number of questions with the them.

Comment: @Chris: I would be able to do that but I'm not sure it really is necessary.  If anything, there should be a [ti-83] tag and is synonymous with [ti-84].  However there is hardly any activity in the tags in the first place, I think it'd be fine to leave as is for now until the tag gets active enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain the length of the list using `dim()`.  That can be found in `2nd->LIST->OPS->dim(`.  Just make sure that you use a list variable otherwise `dim()` will complain about the type.  You could then index into the list with a subscript.

e.g.,

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} -> L1
For (X, 1, dim(L1), 1)
Disp L1(X)
End
```

Comment: You should leave out the step number in a For loop if it is 1.

Answer (score 4):

The for loop is the simplest way to iterate over a list in TI-Basic, as it is in many languages. Jeff Mercado already covered that, so I'll mention a few techniques that are powerful tools in specialized situation.

### Mapping over lists

TI-Basic supports simple mapping operation over lists that have the same effect as a map function in any other language. TI-Basic support for this extends to most basic arithmetic function, and selection of other functions.

The syntax could not be simpler. If you want to add some number `X` to every element in some list `L1` you type  `X+L1→L1`.

### seq(

Most for loops over a lists in TI-Basic can be replaced by cleverly constructed `seq(` command that will outperform the for loop in time and memory. The exceptions to this rule are loops that contain I/O or storing variables.

The syntax for this command can be quite confusing, so I recommend reading over [this documentation](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/seq-list) before using it. In case that link dies, here's the most relevant information.

> Command Summary
>
> Creates a list by evaluating a formula with one variable taking on a
>   range of values, optionally skipping by a specified step.
>
> Command Syntax
>
> seq(formula, variable, start-value, end-value [, step])
>
> Menu Location
>
> While editing a program, press:
>
> 2nd LIST to enter the LIST menu RIGHT to enter the OPS submenu 5 to
>   choose seq(, or use arrows.
>
> Calculator Compatibility
>
> TI-83/84/+/SE
>
> Token Size
>
> 1 byte

The documentation should do a good job explaining the syntax for `seq(`, so I'll just provide a sample use case.

If you want the square of every number between 1 and 100 you could do this

For Loop

```
DelVar L1100→dim(L1
for(A,1,100
A²→L1(A
End
```

or, this

seq

```
seq(A²,A,1,100→L1
```

The drawback of `seq(` is that you can't do any I/O or store any variables inside the expression.

### Predefined list iteration function

Go to the `LIST` menu and check out all the operations under `OPS` and `MATH`. These predefined function are always going to be faster than a for loops or even a `seq(` expression designed to do the same thing.

Comment: `seq(` is best again here in this situation... wow dohaqatar you seem knowledgeable ;)

Comment: @Timtech Thanks! I've been playing with TI-Basic since middle school, so I've had time to pick up quite a bit of knowledge.

Comment: Same here. I guess we've both learned a bit from tibasicdev.wikidot?

Comment: @Timtech I haven't been able to find an accumulation of TI-Basic knowledge that large any where else.

Comment: Me neither. Do you have the owner's manual? I've heard that it's a good source of knowledge as well.